# Free Good-looking Carousel Component for Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, components, flash-builder

Where can I find a free **but** good-quality and customizable carousel component for Flex 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I came upon this nice clean carousel component written specifically for Flex 4, and it's free:
http://webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/3d-carousel-layout-flex

FTQuest

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet but it seems to be exactly what I need! (Based on the demo on the page.)

Answer (score 2):

Loook at that.
http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/displayShelf/index.html

Tour de Flex is full of good libraries.

Claudio.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular one was built by Doug McCune.  It is not built natively in Spark, but source code is available and you can recompile it for Flex 4.

I thought it was part of [Flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/), but since I don't see it listed [look here](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/11/19/flex-coverflow-performance-improvement-flex-carousel-component-and-vertical-coverflow/).

Comment: Hmm... I tried it out but it gives me an error? How do I go about "recompiling it for Flex 4" ?

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu download the source code and put it in a Flex 4 project and compile.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking specifically for free, but a great resource for components (including quite a few carousels) along with source code can be found at http://activeden.net/ for darn near free (a few dollars).  Hope that helps.